# Update/append values in text file using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote a code that takes user input and saves it as a text file.

```
from tkinter import * 

def save_info():
    question_info = question.get()
    choices_info = choices.get()
    correct_answer_info = correct_answer.get()
    marks_info = marks.get()
    time_info = time.get()
    
    #print('all values')
    
    file = open("user.txt","w")
    
    file.write(question_info)
    
    file.write("\n")
    
    file.write(choices_info)
    
    file.write("\n")
    
    file.write(correct_answer_info)
    
    file.write("\n")
    
    file.write(str(marks_info))
    
    file.write("\n")
    
    file.write(str(time_info))
    
    file.close()
    
    

app = Tk()

app.geometry("600x600")

app.title("Assesment Question")

heading = Label(text="Enter the Asked Information",fg="black",bg="yellow",width="500",height="3",font="10")

heading.pack()

question_text = Label(text="Question")
choices_text = Label(text="Choices separated by #")
correct_answer_text = Label(text="Correct Answer")
marks_text = Label(text='Marks')
time_text = Label(text="Time in seconds")

question_text.place(x=15,y=70)
choices_text.place(x=15,y=140)
correct_answer_text.place(x=15,y=210)
marks_text.place(x=15,y=280)
time_text.place(x=15,y=350)

question = StringVar()
choices = StringVar()
correct_answer = StringVar()
marks = IntVar()
time = IntVar()

question_entry = Entry(textvariable=question,width="30")
choices_entry = Entry(textvariable=choices,width="30")
correct_answer_entry = Entry(textvariable=correct_answer,width="30")
marks_entry = Entry(textvariable=marks,width="30")
time_entry = Entry(textvariable=time,width="30")

question_entry.place(x=15,y=100)
choices_entry.place(x=15,y=180)
correct_answer_entry.place(x=15,y=240)
marks_entry.place(x=15,y=300)
time_entry.place(x=15,y=380)

button = Button(app,text="Submit Data",command=save_info,width="30",height="2",bg="grey")

button.place(x=15,y=420)


mainloop()
```

Right now, when i want to add new data to my text file the values get modified.

Is there any way i can update my text file by appending the new data instead of overwriting it?

I want an output in txt file like this:

Ques1

Choices1

correct_ans1

marks1

time1

Ques2

Choices2

correct_ans2

marks2

time2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is.   Use `file = open("user.txt","a")`, as the documentation says.

```
print('\n'.join([question_info, choices_info, correct_answer_info, str(marks_info), (time_info)]), file=file)
```

I use `print` because it also adds a trailing newline, which you were not doing.

Alternatively:

```
print( f"{question_info}\n{choices_info}\n{correct_answer_info}\n{marks_info}\n{time_info}", file=file)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didnt know u can create a new file with "a".

Comment: Note that `marks_info` and `time_info` are integers (get from `IntVar`), so the `join()` will fail with exception.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't notice they were IntVars.  So, my chiding was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple
just use

```
file = open("user.txt","a")
```

instead of

```
file = open("user.txt","w")
```

what this 'a' does is it opens the file in append mode which means it will add new data to your file along with previous data.
if you use 'w' write mode, it adds new data but will delete the previous data.
so u will always end up with only the data u entered just now.